# How do I find the index of a record in a TList?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I'm trying to build up a count of the number of times each ProductCode is used in my database. The problem being, I don't know what all the codes are (or more may be added).

I'm assuming I could use a TList, with value pairs (productCode and count) to do this something like this (I'm trying to treat this like an List<> from c#, etc.)

```
procedure myProc
type 
  TProductCodeCount = record
     productCode : string;
     count : integer;
  end;
var
  productCodes : TList<TProductCodeCount>;
  newProductCodeCount : TProductCodeCount;
  currProductCodeCount : TProductCodeCount;
  currentProductCode : string;
  productCodeIndex : integer;
begin
  productCodes :=  TList<TProductCodeCount>.Create;

  // Get my data set
  // Loop through my data set
    begin
      currentProductCode := // value from the database ;
      productCodeIndex := productCodes.indexOf(currentProductCode);
      if productCodeIndex = -1 then
      begin
        newProductCodeCount.productCode := currentProductCode;
        newProductCodeCount.count := 1;

        productCodes.Add(newProductCodeCount)
    end
    else
    begin
      currProductCodeCount := productCodes.Extract(productCodeIndex);
      currProductCodeCount.count := currProductCodeCount.count + 1'
      productCodes.Delete(productCodeIndex);
      productCodes.Add (currProductCodeCount);
    end
  end;

  // Loop through my TList
  begin
     // do something with each productCode and count.
  end
end;
```

There are two big things wrong here.

1. I'm not sure how to code the comparison for the indexOf to work (if that's even possible for a TList of a record-type
2. The update of the list item is clunky.

How can I do the comparison? Or is there a much better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why a list of value pairs? If you have XE7, you can use a TDictionary<string, Integer>. The comparison can then be done by passing the result of TComparer<string>.Construct(...here comes the code of the comparison ...) to the dictionary at creation time.

Comment: I'm not pretty good at databases but I would expect that something like this could be done on database level. If the field productCode is Indexed then the database already has all different entries stored in its index table. How to retrieve these I don't know. Also I'm pretty sure that most databases alows you to get number of records that fit specific query without actually retriving them. So all you would need is to make certain query for each specific productCode to see how many record contain that specific productCode.

Comment: Couldn't you just run `SELECT ProductCode, COUNT(ProductCode) FROM Products GROUP BY ProductCode`?

Comment: @Rudy using Dictionary is not bad way to go, you don't have to add any kind of comparer in that case.

Comment: @SilverWarior and RobKennedy - you're right, I could do a DB query and then walk the result set. I've kind of contrived my example here. In reality I'm modifying some existing code, and I've been passed a TOraQuery that I don't want to modify, and they are already walking the result set for another reason.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, the TDictionary makes a lot of sense and should make this much cleaner.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: In this case, I guess the default comparer would do. But only if a simple string comparison of ProductCode is enough.

Comment: n.b., Thanks all. I Went back and used the TList method (with a custom 'comparer') as it became much more convenient to do some other things like sorting, and walking the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use custom comparer that you will pass to `TList<T>` during construction.

```
type
  TProductCodeCountComparer = class(TComparer<TProductCodeCount>)
  public
    function Compare(const Left, Right: TProductCodeCount): Integer; override;
  end;

function TProductCodeCountComparer.Compare(const Left, Right: TProductCodeCount): Integer; 
begin
  Result := CompareStr(Left.productCode, Right.productCode);
end;

var
  Comparer: IComparer<TProductCodeCount>

Comparer := TProductCodeCountComparer.Create;
productCodes :=  TList<TProductCodeCount>.Create(Comparer);
```

You can also create comparer in place

```
  productCodes := TList<TProductCodeCount>.Create(
    TComparer<TProductCodeCount>.Construct(
    function (const Left, Right: TProductCodeCount): Integer
      begin
        Result := CompareStr(Left.productCode, Right.productCode);
      end));
```

For editing records in place you can use `TList<T>.List` property that gives you direct access to underlying `TList<T>` array and enables you to directly modify records in list:

```
var
  productCodes: TList<TProductCodeCount>;
....
inc(productCodes.List[productCodeIndex].count);
```

`TList<T>.List` property was introduced in XE3, for earlier Delphi versions following class extension enables in place record modifications:

```
  TXList<T> = class(TList<T>)
  protected type
    PT = ^T;
  function GetPItem(index: Integer): PT;
  public
    property PItems[index: Integer]: PT read GetPItem;
  end;

function TXList<T>.GetPItem(index: Integer): PT;
begin
  Result := @FItems[index];
end;

var
  productCodes: TXList<TProductCodeCount>;
....
inc(productCodes.PItems[productCodeIndex].count);
```

Comment: You should better use `Result := CompareStr( ... );`

Comment: It's much easier to use `TComparer<T>.Construct` and not bear the overhead of making a new class.

Comment: @David I prefer classes because they can be reused and tested more easily and code is more readable.

Comment: You can reuse the comparer returned by Construct and it is just as readable.

Comment: @David for answer completeness I included in place creation of comparer too.

Comment: I agree with David. For custom comparisons, it is much easier to generate a new IComparer<x> using Construct than to derive a totally new class. The anonmeth for Construct can be a simple named function or method as well as an ad-hoc piece of code, and the former can be reusable as well.

Comment: @Dalija That can be done using `TList<T>.List`. That's why that property exists. Again much cleaner than making yet another class